# Whats the thing going wrong here?

Tags: ruby

The following piece of code in Ruby is not compiling. Can anyone help me know why? I've been at it for hours, but no result. :(

Code snippet:

```
    for i in 0..followers.length
    for j in 0..followers[i].length
    end
end
```

Why does this piece of code keep throwing an error saying:

```
the .length is undefined for nil:NilClass(NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the context for this code, here is the point fix:

```
for i in 0..followers.length
  if followers[i] # for some value of i followers[i] is nil
    for j in 0..followers[i].length
    end
  end
end
```

The error was caused because for some value of `i`, `followers[i]` is `nil`.